# How to make a button that opens a link in google?

Tags: android

So I'm making a app that views certain surveys on the device, but the thing is that the device doesn't want to load the webview. How would I go about changing the button to instead open the survey link in google?

Comment: `in google` Google Chrome you mean?

Comment: Yeah- the default web browser for android

Comment: So basically you want to open a specific website when button is clicked?

Comment: Yes- but externally to the app

Comment: always remember that you have to use search before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override 
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.yourURL.com"));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: That looks like it would work. I’ll try it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On **Button** click (onClick) set this event:

```
Uri link = Uri.parse("http://www.yourwebsite.xx"); 
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, link);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will open you URL.